# Angular - Facebook Login opens window saying: "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-login

Facebook login operation from angular component opens window saying: "Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Go Back"

yesterday it works fine. i tried debug it yet i didn't found anything. The console shows undefined in "@login.component.ts:58"
which is where i catch errors. i deleted all the cookies, cache and history from the browser(chrome). i reserved the app. i tried to look for answer in google didn't found anything that helped.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private FB: FacebookService) {
    let initParams: InitParams = {
      appId: 'my-app-id',
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v3.2'
    };

    FB.init(initParams);
  }

ngOnInit() {
(window as any).fbAsyncInit = function() {
  this.FB.init({
    appId      : 'my-app-id',
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v3.2'
  });
  this.FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id) {
   let js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return; }
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }

  facebookLogin() {
     debugger;
     const loginOptions: LoginOptions = {
      enable_profile_selector: true,
      return_scopes: true,
      scope: 'user_birthday,default,email',
      auth_type: 'rerequest'
};
this.FB.login(loginOptions)
  .then((response: LoginResponse) => {
    let array = response.authResponse.grantedScopes.split(',');
    if(array.length === 3) {

    } else {
       alert('You need to provide all the facebook permissions to use the app.');
    }
 })
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
   }
```

i expect "continue as myName" window yet i get "Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can. window

**EDIT 1**
the next section don't open the window "Continue as my-name"
but it does return an object with token ,user id etc, and doesn't throw exception:

```
facebookLogin() {
this.FB.login()
  .then((response: LoginResponse) => console.log(response));
}
```

i still need the window to ask for permissions.

Comment: In the constructor `FB.init(initParams);`, isn't this should be `this.FB.init(initParams);`?

Comment: @Jai because its in the same function that it's being called than no. anyway, i tried it, and it didn't help. thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution: 
 the problem was writing the .then one line down
so instead of:

```
this.FB.login(loginOptions)
.then((response: LoginResponse) =>
```

i should have done this:

```
this.FB.login(loginOptions).then((response: LoginResponse) =>
```

also the scope property in the loginOptions must contain: 'public_profile'

```
const loginOptions: LoginOptions = {
  enable_profile_selector: true,
  return_scopes: true,
  scope: 'email,public_profile',
  auth_type: 'rerequest'
};
```